# express API not executing my most recent changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Ok so I'm building my first ever API, I'm using express and I've noticed alot of inconsistencies, alot of times i upload my changes to the server and when I use postman to try those changes it always returns me the previous response. I'm wondering if its cause of postman or maybe its a problem with my API.
Heres the current code for my API, as you can see its really simple:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client/build")));

app.get("/ping", function (req, res) {
  return res.send("pong");
});

app.get("/api/blog", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/blog/blog.json"));
});

app.post("/api/blog", (req, res) => {
  const fs = require('fs');
  var filePath = "./blog/blog.json";
  res.send("alo");

});

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/client/build/index.html"));
});
```

here's my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "first",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share your package.json file.

Comment: edited the post to include it

Comment: Is that your entire server file? How/where are you uploading it to? Could also be some caching issue

Comment: pretty much this file already existed and it was made by someone else, it was used to present a react app in a website, the thing is i was asked to do something that couldnt be done client side, so i tried to change that server file in order to accept a post, the problem is sometimes it works and some times it doesnt, its very inconsistent.